# QGIS Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin Error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, classification, random-forest

I loaded the SCP (Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin) in the QGIS. I want to perform Random Forest Classfication operation with using SCP. However, the following errors raising;
I don't know how to fixed this error. How to solve this problem?

[image: Python path]
[image]

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Did you google the error? Did you make contact with the provider of the plugin? Have you checked for similar errors?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find a solution. For the solution, I added the python path to the python executable path section, but this time it get into a bug and did not do the classification process. Actually I don't know what to write in "python executable path" and "python module path".